# how to make firebug in a xul application

Tags: firebug, xul

my code like this

```
<window>
<browser id="browser"
       flex="1"
       src="http://www.google.com" />
<window>
```

and now i want install firebug in my sample app, how to do

Comment: Maybe I'm just ignorant, but Firebug is a Firefox extension. How would you install a Firefox extension in a Firefox extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've built a XULRunner application, then you may have trouble integrating Firebug because it probably makes assumptions about the internals of Firefox. You could probably install DOM Inspector and/or Venkman into your application, since they will automatically install into any XULRunner application based on Gecko 1.9.1 or later, but you would still have to provide your own UI entry points (or use the command line to open them).